# Saving values in memory using ASP.NET Core v2

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

Using Razorpage I have a 5 Select Boxes populated onPageLoad from SQL queries using C# Lists containing Key and Value

When saving the form I need to get hold of the key and values in these lists again

So to prevent more queries to SQL I would like to store the list (key, value pair) in memory on load so I can access it later using C#

how can I do that?

I am using ASP.NET Core v2 and C#

Thanks

Thomas

Comment: Are those values session based or the same for everyone? If they are the same for everyone you could save them in a MemoryCache cache item.

Comment: yes they are the same for all users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `IMemoryCache`

In your Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMemoryCache();
    }
}
```

In your controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IMemoryCache _cache;

    public HomeController(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
        _cache = memoryCache;
    }
}
```

And then fetch it

```
 var cacheEntry = _cache.GetOrCreate("your-cache-key", entry =>
 {
    entry.SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);

    // return your key/value list;
    return new Dictionary<string,string>();
 }
```

See for more information [In-memory caching in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory)